# _window ivar in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c

Created an empty project in Xcode, which merely sets up the App Delegate with a window object.

While AppDelegate.h creates a `@property` for `window`:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;`

There is no mention in either the `.h` or `.m` of the ivar `_window` however the `dealloc` shows:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
[_window release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

So my question is, does an `@property` automatically create an ivar with an underscore for the associate ivar for the property? I thought that unless you write something like `@synthesize window=_window` then properties and ivars have the same name. However there is no such (or any) `@synthesize` statement in the `.m` so where is the `_window` coming from?

Comment: the question prompted a lot of useful information in the answers and commments, so not sure why this was downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLVM 4.0, the default compiler for Xcode 4.4, provides a new feature called *auto-synthesis* that will automatically synthesize declared properties (unless they're declared in a protocol). In addition to synthesizing getter and setter (if necessary) implementations, auto-synthesis will also synthesize an instance variable prefixed with an underscore. So given the following declaration...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *foo;
```

...the compiler will synthesize an instance variable named `_foo` as well as`foo` and `setFoo:` method implementations that access `_foo`.

Comment: Thanks. Accepting your answer as the other answer, though first, was incorrect on several important points when initially provided here. I'd rather have accurate answers than quick answers. :)

Comment: @andrewx the only unspecified thing in my answer was not saying that with the new version of the compiler '@synthesize' could be omitted on certain situations ... I don't think my answer is a bad answer, however your opinion ...

Comment: sorry @aleroot but your original answer before edits contained a fair amount of misleading inaccuracies. it's ok, we're all learning here.

Answer (score 1):

No, the corresponding ivar is created automatically by the `@property` / `@synthesize` mechanism. The compiler automatically creates the ivar with the default naming convention(the name of the ivar equal to the property name), you can't see it, but it exist and you can refer to it.

With the statement :

```
@synthesize window=_window;
```

you are synthesizing a property with an ivar name equal to the default.

You can specify another name for the ivar different from the default, in this way :

```
@synthesize window=iVarWindow;
```

**Notes**

In the first case you are specifying a name for the ivar with an underscore in front(in the default implementation the name of the ivar would have been equal to the name of the property) , while in the second case you are specifying a custom name.

If you don't synthesize the property(with `@synthesize` in the implementation file), the compiler doesn't generate accessor methods automatically, in this case you have to write accessor methods on your own or you will not have them ! Anyway the ivar is created by the `@property`, so even if you don't have the `@synthesize` you have the ivar related to the property, *otherwise How could you been able to write your own implementation of accessor methods without the ivar ?* :-)

---

***Update***

With the new version of Xcode 4.4 the compiler will generate automatically accessor methods even without and @synthesize statement for property.

Comment: I guess my point is that _window is never mentioned anywhere in the .h or .m, nor is there any @synthesize statement; so how does _window get created?

Comment: I thought `@synthesize` statements were needed if an `@property` statement existed? How can the AppDelegate omit the `@synthesize` altogether?

Comment: @synthesize is needed to let the compiler create the getters and setters for the specified property, if you don't have synthesize you don't have accessor methods for the property ...

Comment: With the latest compiler you can leave out the `@synthesize`. Accessors will be automatically generated. Also, I think the code in `-dealloc` should more properly be `self.window = nil`

Comment: @nielsbot It's common to use the instance variables directly in `init` and `dealloc`. The reason is mostly that using the setter could have unwanted side effects with KVO.

Comment: `@synthesize window=_window;` is _not_ the same as `@synthesize window;`. The latter would use the name of the property as the name of the instance variable. Leaving out the `@synthesize` statement entirely however is the same as `@synthesize window=_window` in Xcode 4.4 (with the latest compiler).

Comment: There is still a discrepancy between what @nielsbot and @aleroot are saying with regards to accessors being generated without the `@synthesize` statement. @aleroot says they will not be created, but @nielsbot says they will.

Comment: @andrewx It depends on the compiler version you are using, with the latest compiler they will be automatically created ...

Comment: I recommend you change this sentence in your answer to make that clear: "f you don't synthesize the property(with @synthesize in the implementation file), the compiler doesn't generate accessor methods automatically, in this case you have to write accessor methods on your own or you will not have them ! "

Comment: @andrewx i recommend you to specify the version of the compiler you use in your question next time ...

Comment: that's a bit unfair as I was asking a question that I did not know was related to the compiler. no need to downvote for that; that is afterall the point of asking questions.

Comment: @omz--I see your point, but my preference is to only use ivars directly in the accessor for a property. There shouldn't be any side effects from observing a property change on a disappearing object, except for perhaps extra work being done, right?

Comment: Also, with ARC you wouldn't need to dealloc your properties in dealloc. (you can omit the whole method most of the time actually)